# Logstash mixed logs - multiline and normal

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-file

I use input file to get logs like this:

```
input {
  file {
  path => "/home/ec2-user/*.log"
  }
}
```

In one of the log files some events are loging with 1 line:

```
2018-12-10 10:01:30.1097|0|Services.Services|INFO|  Message: test
```

Another are multilines like this one :

```
2018-12-10 10:01:30.1097|0|Services.Services|INFO|  Message: {
"account_id": "ec812648-3857-4625-9d9a-fc8ce1835493",
"name": "Player_539017",
"creation_time": "10/12/2018 10:52:52",
"hq_level": 2,
"force": 2570
} successfully dequeued |url: |action:
```

How can I capture both of the messages with logstash filter:

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example from [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/6.2/plugins-codecs-multiline.html#_description_154) page which uses the multiline codec to capture log lines starting with a date timestamp as single event. This will work for both of the log events mentioned above.

```
file {
  path => "/home/ec2-user/*.log"
  codec => multiline {
    # Grok pattern names are valid
    pattern => "^%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601} "
    negate => true
    what => "previous"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks ben5556 - everything is parsing fine now!